# c# parsing, or creating int and string from readline

Tags: c#

I am brand new to programming, and this is for a class so I am not looking for the answer just some things to further research and consider

i want the writelines at the end to say 'the average of [input1], [input2], &[input3] is [answer of average] with a remainder of [remainder]'

I can get the average and the remainder on separate lines, but i cant combine the readlines into a string. any help is greatly appreciated

```
 using System;

   public class Week1
{
   public static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      int variable1;
      int variable2;
      int variable3;
      //test
      int average;
      int sum;
      int remainder;
      string thelist;
      string variable11;
      string variable21;
      string variable31;

      Console.Write( "Enter a number:" );
      variable1 = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
      variable11 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() );

      Console.Write( "Enter another number:" );
      variable2 = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() ); 
      variable21 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() );

      Console.Write("one more:");
      variable3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
      variable31 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() );

      sum = variable1 + variable2 + variable3;

      average = sum / 3;

      remainder = sum % 3;

      thelist= variable11 + variable21 + variable31;

      Console.WriteLine( "THE AVERAGE of ", thelist , average); 
      Console.WriteLine( "THE remainder: {0}", remainder );
      //need spaces before quotes

         Console.ReadLine();

   }
}
```

Comment: This code looking for two input integers each time, is this expected?

Comment: try to use `string.Join`

Comment: you can use `string.Format`

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Suggestions For you:

- In your code you need to Give Two inputs for each variable(use one `Console.ReadLine()` for one input)
- You need not to convert `Console.ReadLine()` to string since It [returns a String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Use Double to store Average otherwise You will get only integer par of the result.(if result is `12.3` it will give you `12`)
- You have to use [`int32.tryparse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) For conversion from string to Integer to avoid exception.
- Use Placeholders for format your output as you wish.

  ```
      int variable1, variable2, variable3, sum, reminder;
      double average;
      string variable11, variable21, variable31;
      Console.Write("Enter a number:");
      variable11 = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Enter another number:");
      variable21 = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("one more:");
      variable31 = Console.ReadLine();
      // Now you have three variables in your hand 
      // You can play with them as you wish
      //Converting each them to an integer 
      if (!Int32.TryParse(variable11, out variable1))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Show error ; Conversion failed");
      }
      if (!Int32.TryParse(variable21, out variable2))
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Show error ; Conversion failed");
      }
      if (!Int32.TryParse(variable31, out variable3))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Show error ; Conversion failed");
      }
      //Performing operations:
      sum = variable1 + variable2 + variable3;
      average =(double)sum / 3;
      reminder = sum % 3;
      //Formating the Output:
      Console.WriteLine("The Operation Result");
      Console.WriteLine("The Sum of {0},{1},{2} is {3} , AVERAGE is{4} and Reminder is {5}",variable1,variable2,variable3,sum,average,reminder );
      Console.ReadKey();
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! i think i figured out on my own but will incorporate this for more advanced programs.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you capturing 2 variables after each question? You can just get one and convert it to `string` where needed.

As pointed out by un-lucky & Hari Prasad, your average is declared as an `integer` which can only store whole numbers. Try making it a `double` or `decimal` instead.

```
using System;

public class Week1
{

    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int variable1;
        int variable2;
        int variable3;
        //test
        double average; //declared as double to capture the decimal values
        int sum;
        int remainder;
        string thelist;
        string variable11;
        string variable21;
        string variable31;

        Console.Write( "Enter a number:" );
        variable1 = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
        //variable11 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() ); not needed.

        Console.Write( "Enter another number:" );
        variable2 = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() ); 
        //variable21 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() ); not needed

        Console.Write("one more:");
        variable3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        //variable31 = Convert.ToString32( Console.ReadLine() ); not needed

        sum = variable1 + variable2 + variable3;

        average = sum / 3;

        remainder = sum % 3;
        //pass the values in and use placeholders {0} to {5}
        Console.WriteLine( "the average of {0}, {1}, & {3} is {4} with a remainder of {5}" , variable1 , variable2, variable3, average, remainder); 
        Console.WriteLine( "THE remainder: {0}", remainder );
        //need spaces before quotes

         Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Also one more update you can include, average declared as `int` but should be `decimal` or `double`

Comment: I couldnt make yours work Jeff, but did edit it to the following                             
        //pass the values in and use placeholders {0} to {5}
        Console.WriteLine("the average of {0}, {1}, & {2} is {3} with a remainder of {4}", variable1, variable2, variable3, average, remainder);
        //Console.WriteLine("THE remainder: {0}", remainder);
        //need spaces before quotes

        Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

i solved it another way. appreciate all the feedback!

```
using System;

public class Week1
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int variable1;
    int variable2;
    int variable3;
    //int[] arr = new int[2];
    //for (variable1 = 0; variable1 < 3; variable1++)
    //for (variable2 = 0; variable2 < 3; variable2++)
    //test

    int average;
    int sum;
    int remainder;


    Console.Write("Enter a number:");
    variable1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //arr[variable1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter another number:");
    variable2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //arr[variable2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("one more:");
    variable3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            sum = variable1 + variable2 + variable3;

            average = sum / 3;

            remainder = sum % 3;

    Console.WriteLine("The average of " + variable1
    + ", " + variable2 + ", " + variable3 + " is "
    + average + " with a remainder of " + remainder);

    //Console.WriteLine("THE remainder: {0}", remainder);
    //need spaces before quotes

    //Console.ReadLine();

}
```

}